# Excel Formulas to Determine Discounts

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to determine if a discount should be applied. If the payment method was Express Miles or Rewards, the discount is received. If no discount should be applied the formula should return a zero. I am having trouble setting up the part of the formula that applies to "Express Miles" **OR** "Rewards". Can anyone help?

Comment: Umm what kind of logic triggers Express Miles or Reqards? You need to provide a lot more detail if you want help. We are not mind readers.

Comment: Add a mock up or post a link to a screenshot at a sharing site like imgur.com.  Where does Express Miles or Rewards come from and what form is it in (e.g., text input, selection from a pull-down menu)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Yes, we can help, but you have not given us enough information to be able to do so. Please read ***[ask]***, then add details to your question so we can help you. Including an example of how your data is laid out and the formula you are working with will speed things up considerably.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want it to do, or what we're looking for as other users have pointed out, but here goes!

=IF(A2=OR("express miles","rewards"),do this if true,do this if false)

In this example I've assumed cell A2 has either 'express miles', or 'rewards' in it. it looks for those and then if it finds either of them, it will do whatever you put instead of "do this if true" If it can't find them it will do whatever you put instead of "Do this if false"

Comment: If you test your formula, I think you'll find that it will produce an error message regardless of what's in A2 (wrong syntax).

Comment: What @Thomb is trying to say is:  =IF(OR(A2="express miles", A2="rewards")...

Comment: Which I explained in the second line - how can you assume there's a syntax error when all I've given is a suggested function?